# Error Running Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise

I am developing my web parts in SharePoint 2010 and have code analysis framework installed. I have 4 (1 is SharePoint project other are class libraries) projects in my SharePoint solution. All build OK. But when I try to run code analysis from VS 2010 on my SharePoint project it fails with an error "Couldn't load assembly

What the problem behind this.

Comment: its trying to load any external assembly that isn't in GAC or place where it has been referenced to

Comment: Yes I do have references from GAC. How to deal with it?